# Is there any way to enforce string length or truncate strings at query time using a SOAP SOQL query?

Tags: soap

I've run into some data where the string in salesforce is bigger than the allowed size according to the description of the object. While I could grab the entire string and truncate it locally, I'd like to know if anyone has implemented a mechanism to do this on the salesforce side.

My requirement is that I have to be able to send a request via SOAP, and get back records that don't violate the sobject description. Any way this could be accomplished, I'd love to hear about.

Comment: There's no truncation mechanism in pure SOQL.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what kind of string is exceeding the sObject field description? I'm not totally certain how that can happen once a record has been saved unless it's being escaped during transmission which would add additional characters. Unescaping it on your end should solve that issue for you.

Comment: I cant provide the real data per our security policy. Two situations can lead to this problem, though: 1. If you change the definition of an object by shortening the length of a string attribute, records which existed before the change will still have the full length and 2. Data loaded into salesforce through third party tools can sometimes be written to exceed the attribute definition.